# Spark NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running spark using the following Docker command:

```
docker run -it \
  -p 8088:8088 -p 8042:8042 -p 50070:50070 \
  -v "$(PWD)"/log4j.properties:/usr/local/spark/conf/log4j.properties \
  -v "$(PWD)":/app -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 bash
```

Running `spark-submit --version` reports version `1.6.0`

My `spark-submit` command is the following:

```
spark-submit --class io.jobi.GithubDay \
  --master local[*] \
  --name "Daily Github Push Counter" \
  /app/min-spark_2.11-1.0.jar \
  "file:///app/data/github-archive/*.json" \
  "/app/data/ghEmployees.txt" \
  "file:///app/data/emp-gh-push-output" "json"
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := """min-spark"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

lazy val sparkVersion = "1.6.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
)

// Change this to another test framework if you prefer
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
```

**GithubDay.scala**

```
package io.jobi

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.io.Source.fromFile

/**
  * Created by hammer on 7/15/16.
  */
object GithubDay {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Application arguments: ")
    args.foreach(println)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)


    try {
      println("args(0): " + args(0))

      val ghLog = sqlContext.read.json(args(0))
      val pushes = ghLog.filter("type = 'PushEvent'")
      val grouped = pushes.groupBy("actor.login").count()
      val ordered = grouped.orderBy(grouped("count").desc)

      val employees = Set() ++ (
        for {
          line <- fromFile(args(1)).getLines()
        } yield line.trim
      )

      val bcEmployees = sc.broadcast(employees)

      import sqlContext.implicits._
      println("register function")
      val isEmployee = sqlContext.udf.register("SetContainsUdf", (u: String) => bcEmployees.value.contains(u))
      println("registered udf")
      val filtered = ordered.filter(isEmployee($"login"))
      println("applied filter")

      filtered.write.format(args(3)).save(args(2))
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
    }
  }
}
```

I build using `sbt clean package` but the output when I run it is:

```
Application arguments:
file:///app/data/github-archive/*.json
/app/data/ghEmployees.txt
file:///app/data/emp-gh-push-output
json
args(0): file:///app/data/github-archive/*.json
imported implicits
defined isEmp
register function
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaUniverse$JavaMirror;
    at io.jobi.GithubDay$.main(GithubDay.scala:53)
    at io.jobi.GithubDay.main(GithubDay.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

From what I've read `NoSuchMethodError` is a result of version incompatibilities, but I'm building with `1.6.0` and deploying to `1.6.0` so I don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've compiled Spark yourself, out of the box version 1.6.0 is compiled with Scala 2.10.x. [This is stated in the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#downloading) (which says 1.6.2, but is also relevant to 1.6.0):

> Spark runs on Java 7+, Python 2.6+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API,
>   Spark 1.6.2 uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala
>   version (2.10.x).

You want:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
```

One hint to that is that the error is in a Scala class: `scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)`